# How i could prove this:$F(x)=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \cos^{x}\! \theta \cos(x\theta){\mathrm{d}}\theta$= $\frac{\pi}{2^{a+1}}, \quad$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

for   $ a=x>-1$

prove that:

$F(x)=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \cos^{x}\! \theta \cos(x\theta){\mathrm{d}}\theta$= $\frac{\pi}{2^{a+1}}, \quad$

I would be interest for any replies or any comments

Comment: I don't see $b$ anywhere in the expression.

Comment: In general, $~\displaystyle\int_0^\frac\pi2\cos^nx\cos(ax)dx=\dfrac\pi{2^{n+1}}\cdot{n \choose [n-a]/2}$, see [Wallis' integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis'_integrals) for more details.

Comment: my problem is not in general , but in  a special case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^{a}\pars{\theta}\cos\pars{b\theta}\,\dd\theta
     ={\pi \over 2^{a+1}}:\ {\large ?}}$.

> $\ds{\large\tt\mbox{I'll consider the case}\quad a\,, b \in {\mathbb R}}$:

\begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
\cos^{a}\pars{\theta}\cos\pars{b\theta}\,\dd\theta}
=\Re\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^{a}\pars{\theta}\expo{\ic b\theta}\,\dd\theta
\\[3mm]&=\Re
\int_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1 \atop {\vphantom{\Huge A}0\ <\ {\rm Arg}\pars{z}\ <\ \pi/2}}
\pars{z^{2} + 1 \over 2z}^{a}z^{b}\,{\dd z \over \ic z}
\\[3mm]&={1 \over 2^{a}}\,\Im\bracks{\color{#00f}{%
\int_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1 \atop {\vphantom{\Huge A}0\ <\ {\rm Arg}\pars{z}\ <\ \pi/2}}
\pars{z^{2} + 1}^{a}z^{b - a - 1}\,\dd z}}\tag{1}
\end{align}

> $\ds{\mbox{With}\ 0 < \epsilon < 1}$:
>   \begin{align}&\color{#00f}{%
> \int_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1 \atop {\vphantom{\Huge A}0\ <\ {\rm Arg}\pars{z}\ <\ \pi/2}}
> \pars{z^{2} + 1}^{a}z^{b - a - 1}\,\dd z}
> \\[3mm]&=-\int_{1}^{\epsilon}\pars{-y^{2} + 1}^{a}y^{b - a - 1}
> \expo{\ic\pars{b - a - 1}\pi/2}\ic\,\dd y
> \\[3mm]&\phantom{=}
> -\int_{\pi/2}^{0}\pars{\epsilon^{2}\expo{2\ic\theta} + 1}^{a}\epsilon^{b - a - 1}
> \expo{\ic\pars{b - a - 1}\theta}\epsilon\expo{\ic\theta}\ic\,\dd\theta
> -\int_{\epsilon}^{1}\pars{x^{2} + 1}^{a}x^{b - a - 1}\,\dd x
> \\[3mm]&=\half\,\expo{\ic\pars{b - a}\pi/2}\int_{\epsilon^{2}}^{1}\pars{1 - y}^{a}
> y^{\pars{b - a}/2 - 1}\,\dd y
> +\ic\epsilon^{b - a}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\pars{\epsilon^{2}\expo{2\ic\theta} + 1}^{a}
> \expo{\ic\pars{b - a}\theta}\,\dd\theta
> \\[3mm]&\phantom{=}-\int_{\epsilon}^{1}\pars{x^{2} + 1}^{a}x^{b - a - 1}\,\dd x
> \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\pars{2}
> \end{align}

When $\ds{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}$ I find
$\ds{\pars{~\mbox{from}\ \pars{1}\ \mbox{and}\ \pars{2}~}}$:
\begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
\cos^{a}\pars{\theta}\cos\pars{b\theta}\,\dd\theta}
={1 \over 2^{a + 1}}\,\sin\pars{\bracks{b - a}\pi \over 2}
\int_{0}^{1}\pars{1 - y}^{a}y^{\pars{b - a}/2 - 1}\,\dd y
\\[3mm]&\mbox{where}\qquad a > -1\,,\quad{b - a \over 2} - 1 > - 1\,,\quad
b - a > 0\qquad\imp\qquad
\begin{array}{|c|}\hline\ b > a > -1\ \\ \hline\end{array}\qquad\pars{3}
\end{align}
$\pars{3}$ guarantees the integrals convergence and the vanishing out of the second term in $\pars{2}$: 
\begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
\cos^{a}\pars{\theta}\cos\pars{b\theta}\,\dd\theta}
={1 \over 2^{a + 1}}\,\sin\pars{\bracks{b - a}\pi \over 2}
{\rm B}\pars{a + 1,{b - a \over 2}}
\end{align}
$\ds{{\rm B}\pars{x,y} = {\Gamma\pars{x}\Gamma\pars{y} \over \Gamma\pars{x + y}}}$
is the
[Beta Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) and $\ds{\Gamma\pars{z}}$ is the
[Gamma Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).
\begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
\cos^{a}\pars{\theta}\cos\pars{b\theta}\,\dd\theta}
={1 \over 2^{a + 1}}\,\sin\pars{\bracks{b - a}\pi \over 2}
{\Gamma\pars{a + 1}\Gamma\pars{\bracks{b - a}/2} \over \Gamma\pars{a/2 + b/2 + 1}}
\end{align}
With [Euler Reflection Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Properties):
\begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
\cos^{a}\pars{\theta}\cos\pars{b\theta}\,\dd\theta}
={1 \over 2^{a + 1}}\,\sin\pars{\bracks{b - a}\pi \over 2}
{\Gamma\pars{a + 1} \over \Gamma\pars{\bracks{a + b}/2 + 1}}\times
\\[3mm]&{\pi \over \sin\pars{\pi\braces{1 - \bracks{b - a}/2}}
\Gamma\pars{1 - \bracks{b - a}/2}}
\end{align}

> \begin{align}&\color{#00f}{\large\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
> \cos^{a}\pars{\theta}\cos\pars{b\theta}\,\dd\theta}
> \\[3mm]&=\color{#00f}{\large{\pi \over 2^{a + 1}}\,
> {\Gamma\pars{a + 1}\over
> \Gamma\pars{1 + \bracks{a + b}/2}\Gamma\pars{1 + \bracks{a - b}/2}}}\,,\qquad
> \verts{b} > a > -1
> \end{align}

$\ds{\Huge\tt ADDENDUM:}$

With $\ds{0 < \mu < 1}$:
\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
\cos^{a}\pars{\theta}\cos\pars{a\theta}\,\dd\theta}
=\Re\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
\cos^{a}\pars{\theta}\expo{-\ic a\theta}\,\dd\theta
\\[3mm]&=\lim_{\mu \to 1^{-}}\Re\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
\pars{\expo{\ic\theta} + \mu\expo{-\ic\theta} \over 2}^{a}
\expo{-\ic a\theta}\,\dd\theta
={1 \over 2^{a}}\lim_{\mu \to 1^{-}}\Re\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
\pars{1 + \mu\expo{-2\ic\theta}}^{a}\,\dd\theta
\\[3mm]&={1 \over 2^{a}}\lim_{\mu \to 1^{-}}\Re\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
{a \choose n}\mu^{n}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\expo{-2\ic n\theta}\,\dd\theta
={1 \over 2^{a}}\lim_{\mu \to 1^{-}}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
{a \choose n}\mu^{n}\
\overbrace{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos\pars{2n\theta}\,\dd\theta}
^{\ds{=\ {\pi \over 2}\,\delta_{n0}}}
\\[3mm]&={\pi \over 2^{a + 1}}\,\lim_{\mu \to 1^{-}}{a \choose 0}\mu^{0}
=\color{#66f}{\Large{\pi \over 2^{a + 1}}}
\end{align}

Comment: @ felix Marin :Thank you for your answer but you are get the general cases that evaluted by Augustin Louis Cauchy ( look my answer), my problem posted concerned a special cases where a=b

Comment: @rafik I put an $\large\tt ADDENDUM$.

Answer (score 2):

I used this formula that Evaluated by Augustin Louis Cauchy:

for $a>-1$ and $0 \leq b<a+2$:

$\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \cos^{a}\! \theta \cos(b\theta)  {\mathrm{d}}\theta = \frac{\pi}{2^{a+1}}\frac{\Gamma(a+1)}{\Gamma(1+\frac{a+b}{2})\Gamma(1+\frac{a-b}{2})}$

it's seems to me for a=b as a special case i get :

$\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \cos^{a}\! \theta \cos(a\theta)  {\mathrm{d}}\theta = \frac{\pi}{2^{a+1}}, \quad a>-1$

Comment: You're funny. Answering your own question and accept it. Mr. Felix's answer is more comprehensive than yours. Just saying

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be to use Euler's identity, and

$$ \exp( i x \theta ) = \cos (x \theta) + i \sin  (x\theta )$$

This should reduce the integral to an exponential type deal.

Comment: I think by euler identity , you will get this:$F(x)=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \cos^{x}\! \theta e^{ix\theta} 
 
 {\mathrm{d}}\theta=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} (\cos\theta  e^{i\theta})^x 
 
 {\mathrm{d}}\theta$ , but you can't get the result